# IntelliJ detects plain text as code within div tags

Tags: html, angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I wonder why IntelliJ detects text within div-tags as code. First I thought it might have to do with AngularJS but even if I deactivate those plugins this behaviour is still there.

[image]

If I replace the div-tags by e.g. p-tags its working.

I have no idea if this is a problem or not but I never heard of anything like that and also can't find anything related on the internet. Hopefully someone can tell me anything about this.

One problem is that the auto-indent wraps each of those "wrong words" into a new line.

/edit

**Solution**: Check Settings -> Language Injections -> Disable "xml:div JavaScript"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you have some language injected into `<div>` tag. Do you have any custom language injections defined? Please check Settings/Language injections

Comment: Thank you very much. I never checked any but xml:div was checked for JavaScript.